Connection between inverted post-order traversal and insertion order in Binary Search Trees

I have a binary search tree.
I do a post-order traversal.
I reverse the order of the sequence of data I get from the post-order traversal (for example by
inserting the data in a stack and then popping them out again.)
Now, I start inserting the new sequence of data in a new, empty BST.
The result is a new BST, which is identical to the original.

My question is why? Is there a fundamental connection between the order you insert data in a BST and the inverted post-order traversal? I understand that the structure of the BTS is determined by the order in which you insert the data, but I cannot find the connection between these two.
This is actually an exercise in my online CS class. I know that the new tree has to be identical to the original, because this is the point of this exercise. What I cannot find is the explanation, I can see no connection.

Consider whether it's possible for multiple BSTs to have the same post-order traversal. What property of BSTs causes post-order traversals to be unique?

In the "update" section, you have answered your own question. This is confusing on Stack Overflow, where questions should be questions and answers should be found in the answer section. You should remove that update section from your post and instead post it as answer. Or alternatively, you can delete the question.

Update: As a friend pointed out, it has to be the root. By inverting post-order traversal, the first node you come across is the root of each sub-tree of the original BTS. So by inserting the same root, results in a copy of the original sub tree, and recursively the whole BST

In a post-order traversal, the nodes are visited in the order: left subtree, right subtree, and then the root node. By reversing this order, the root node is inserted first, followed by the nodes in the right subtree, and finally the nodes in the left subtree.
This reversed order preserves the relative ordering of the nodes in the BST. When inserting the reversed post-order sequence into a new BST, the nodes are placed in the correct position according to the BST properties (all left children are less than the parent, and all right children are greater than the parent).
Therefore, the resulting BST constructed from the reversed post-order traversal sequence will have the same structure as the original BST, with the same relative ordering of nodes.
